# WooCommerce product permalinks

Tags: permalinks, plugins

How can I do to have my product links as mysite.com/name-of-my-product?

I tried the WooCommerce options but I can't remove the base string before the product`s name from the url structure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter for `post_type_link`, and change its value in a callback function.

Sample code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'simple_woo_urls', 10, 2 );

function simple_woo_urls( $url, $post )
{
    if ( 'product' === $post->post_type )
        return home_url( $post->post_name );

    return $url;
}
```